# Android Studio Creating a Project

Tags: android, android-studio, project

When I open up Android Studio and click on new project this comes up...

[image]

How do I get it back to ask me to enter Application name etc. ?

Also, if I reopen a project the dropdown doesn't show Android view like it did before.

[image]

The dropdown now shows Scratches, Project Files, Problems etc. No Android.

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps another sure way would be to reinstall?

Comment: I would recommend to File-->Close Project , and then repeat the project creation or import wizard. it may solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Gabriele,

Thanks for your response and help. That didn't work so I will try to reinstall and hope that does the job. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to go through the File menu, select New Project. The Create New Project screen appears.

The project tab you're clicking is actually the "display mode" of your project structure.
More info about it [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html).

Comment: Hello,

When I create a new project from the file menu it still does the same thing. Thanks for your help :)